# Bitcoin Step by Step [Kindle Edition] by Michael Caughey - worth buying?

Tags: learning

Courtesy of [bitcointalk.org fame](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=133136).

Sure, the Internet is full of free info but some time it might worth to pay for information, doesn't it? The funny thing is that he only sells it as a DRMed Kindle book, not a DRM-free EPUB at least. Though, I developed some practices so far (not sure if good, but I feel comfortable with them) and I have no idea if the author's worldview is compatible with mine.

One thing for sure: I see so many examples around people complicate bitcoin more necessarily than what it is, got hacked, etc.

[Link to the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A1CUQQU).

Comment: A paper book might be worth reading in a few years time: currently the situation is evolving so quickly, it will almost certainly contain too many obsolete informations.

Comment: It is a Kindle only book.

Comment: Still a traditional book it is, I strongly doubt it will get constantly updated as a good wiki page would...

Answer (score 1):

I am skeptical of the book based on the beginning of the review on Amazon:

> In the half hour it took me to read Caughey's e-book

I've been reading and studying Bitcoin for months and I think I still have a lot to learn. It's hard for me to imagine that much could come from reading a book for 30 minutes.

Comment: It's like 65 pages in print on letter size paper.  There are a number of screen shots.  This is why I'm only selling it for $3.99.  The idea is that will save you time.  take about an hour to read and get set up (minus downloading the initial block chain) and your good to go.  I also give credit and links to many other resources about bitcoin.  There is a lot of good information out there.