# Are the original Bitcoin Qt client's developers around and can we ask them to consider a portable version?

Tags: development, bitcoin-core, portable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Make Bitcoin QT Client Portable? (Windows)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6015/how-to-make-bitcoin-qt-client-portable-windows)

That is my conclusion.

It's better to experiment for myself that asking all these questions I have to restrict myself to with the lack of first hand experiment, right?

[Reference 1.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/understanding-speed-vs-fees-on-various-wallets-esp-instawallet-and-original-c) /
[Reference 2.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/bitcoin-step-by-step-kindle-edition-by-michael-caughey-worth-buying) /
[Reference 3.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6015/how-to-make-bitcoin-qt-client-portable-windows)

Comment: Developers can be contacted on #bitcoin-dev @ irc.freenode.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already essentially portable. Just:

- Download and extract the zip package.
- Run bitcoin-qt with the argument `-datadir=.`

Comment: Wow. That was too easy.